# how to deploy a remote event receiver to azure

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, web-application, azure, remote-event-receiver

I created my first event receiver using this [link](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.EventReceivers)

but now i need to deploy the the final version of the app.

1. I think i need to create a web app on azure and publish the web project
2. How do i authenticate to sharepoint now,(what do i need to change in the token.cs file)
3. note this is for production,strict security measure is a must and i dont know if we can bypass the web app to a cheaper solution